# Get output of `posix_spawn`

Tags: c, posix, fork

So I can run a process in Unix / Linux using POSIX, but is there some way I can store / redirect both the STDOUT and STDERR of the process to a file? The `spawn.h` header contains a deceleration of `posix_spawn_file_actions_adddup2` which looks relevant, but I'm not sure quite how to use it.

The process spawn:

`posix_spawn(&processID, (char *)"myprocess", NULL, NULL, args, environ);`

The output storage:

`...?`

Comment: The third paramater of `posix_spwan` is a pointer of type `posix_spawn_file_actions_t` (one you have given as `NULL`). `posix_spawn` will open, close or duplicate file descriptors inherited from the calling process as specified by the `posix_spawn_file_actions_t` object. The `posix_spawn_file_actions_{addclose,adddup2}` functions are used to indicate what happens to which fd.

Comment: @muru - Do you think you could add a working example? I understood the interaction between the functions is done by a "file action", but it's not clear how exactly this fits together, or where the fd location is defined.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Here's a minimal example of modifying file descriptors of a spawned process, saved as `foo.c`:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <spawn.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[], char *env[])
{
    int ret;
    pid_t child_pid;
    posix_spawn_file_actions_t child_fd_actions;
    if (ret = posix_spawn_file_actions_init (&child_fd_actions))
        perror ("posix_spawn_file_actions_init"), exit(ret);
    if (ret = posix_spawn_file_actions_addopen (&child_fd_actions, 1, "/tmp/foo-log", 
            O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, 0644))
        perror ("posix_spawn_file_actions_addopen"), exit(ret);
    if (ret = posix_spawn_file_actions_adddup2 (&child_fd_actions, 1, 2))
        perror ("posix_spawn_file_actions_adddup2"), exit(ret);

    if (ret = posix_spawnp (&child_pid, "date", &child_fd_actions, NULL, argv, env))
        perror ("posix_spawn"), exit(ret);
}
```

What does it do?

- The third parameter of `posix_spwan` is a pointer of type `posix_spawn_file_actions_t` (one you have given as `NULL`). `posix_spawn` will open, close or duplicate file descriptors inherited from the calling process as specified by the `posix_spawn_file_actions_t` object.
- So we start with a `posix_spawn_file_actions_t` object (`chiild_fd_actions`), and initialize it with `posix_spawn_file_actions_init()`.
- Now, the `posix_spawn_file_actions_{addopen,addclose,addup2}` functions can be used to open, close or duplicate file descriptors (after the `open(3)`, `close(3)` and `dup2(3)` functions) respectively.
- So we `posix_spawn_file_actions_addopen` a file at `/tmp/foo-log` to file descriptor `1` (aka stdout).
- Then we `posix_spawn_file_actions_adddup2` fd `2` (aka `stderr`) to fd 1.
- Note that nothing has been opened or duped *yet*. The last two functions simply changed the `child_fd_actions` object to note that these actions are to be taken.
- And finally we use `posix_spawn` with the `child_fd_actions` object.

Testing it out:

```
$ make foo
cc     foo.c   -o foo
$ ./foo
$ cat /tmp/foo-log 
Sun Jan  3 03:48:17 IST 2016
$ ./foo +'%F %R'  
$ cat /tmp/foo-log
2016-01-03 03:48
$  ./foo -d 'foo'  
$ cat /tmp/foo-log
./foo: invalid date ‘foo’
```

As you can see, both stdout and stderr of the spawned process went to `/tmp/foo-log`.

Comment: Note that `posix_spawn*` don't set errno. Thus, you can't use `perror()`. Use something like `fprintf(stderr, "...: %s\n", strerror(ret))` instead. Also, the main function is missing a `return 0` statement.

Comment: In this case do you need to close the fd also?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can. Defining the right list of posix spawn file actions definitely is the way to go.

Example:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <spawn.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>    
#define CHECK_ERROR(R, MSG) do { if (R) { fprintf(stderr, "%s: %s\n",
        (MSG), strerror(R)); return 1; } } while (0)    
extern char **environ;   
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if (argc < 3) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Call: %s OUTFILE COMMAND [ARG]...\n", argv[0]);
        return 2;
    }
    const char *out_filename = argv[1];
    char **child_argv = argv+2;
    posix_spawn_file_actions_t as;
    int r = posix_spawn_file_actions_init(&as);
    CHECK_ERROR(r, "actions init");
    r = posix_spawn_file_actions_addopen(&as, 1, out_filename,
            O_CREAT | O_TRUNC | O_WRONLY, 0644);
    CHECK_ERROR(r, "addopen");
    r = posix_spawn_file_actions_adddup2(&as, 1, 2);
    CHECK_ERROR(r, "adddup2");
    pid_t child_pid;
    r = posix_spawnp(&child_pid, child_argv[0], &as, NULL,
            child_argv, environ);
    CHECK_ERROR(r, "spawnp");
    r = posix_spawn_file_actions_destroy(&as);
    CHECK_ERROR(r, "actions destroy");
    return 0;
}
```

Compile and test:

```
$ cc -Wall -g -o spawnp spawnp.c
$ ./spawnp log date -I
$ cat log
2018-11-03
$ ./a.out log dat 
spawnp: No such file or directory
```

Note that the `posix_spawn` functions don't set errno, instead, unlike most other UNIX functions, they return an error code. Thus, we can't use `perror()` but have to use something like `strerror()`.

We use two spawn file actions: addopen and addup2. The addopen is similar to a normal `open()` but you also specify a file descriptor which is automatically closed if already open (here 1, i.e. stdout). The addup2 has similar effects to `dup2()`, i.e. the target file descriptor (here 2, i.e. stderr) is atomically closed before 1 is duplicated to 2. Those actions are only executed in the child created by `posix_spawn`, i.e. right before it execs the specified command.

Like `fork()`, `posix_spawn()` and `posix_spawnp()` immediately return to the parent. Thus, we have to use `waitid()` or `waitpid()` to explicitly wait on `child_pid`'s termination.